# how to create a group of buttons in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-gui

I want to create a button as given below. Two circles and four buttons are enough.
I couldn't find an exact method to do it. So I am trying to create a custom button using masking.
 I could create two circle and I set it when middle area(green circle) is clicked, it calls one activity and the button(blue circle) area is clicked,it called another activity. Now I want to cut this area(blue area) to four buttons.
Is there any exact method to do this?

trouble I met in masking : I couldn't create a 90 degree of a circle.

button I want to create

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/912/MAtO3I.png

button I have created

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/538/fPqERc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First of all use FrameLayout. In this frame layout put ImageView. In this Imageview put your image "http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/912/MAtO3I.png". in second layout of this frame layout arrange ImageViews in RelativeLayout with blank source of ImageView and give them a ClickListner.